# Changing a specific thing in a varible

Tags: javascript, html, math

I have a equation like this stored in a varible
(50 * 1.07^1) its very simple. I want to know how I can change the power each time a function runs like so: 50*1.07^2, 50*1.07^3 and so forth. Any help?
Here is my code:

```
var mathForCost = 50 * 1.07 ^ 1;

function gainCoinsPS() {
    if (coins >= costPS) {
        coinsPS += 10;
        coins -= costPS;
        // Here is where I am changing the cost each time the function runs, 
        // so I need to make the power(^1) add 1 each time
        costPS = document.getElementById("changePrice1").innerHTML = "Cost: " + costPS;
    } else {;
        alert("You dont have enough coins!");
    };

}
```

Comment: Save the power in a variable then create your equation using that variable? Please show us some code that showcases your issue and what you have done or thought of as solutions.

Comment: I added my code does it help?

Comment: In Javascript you can't really store an equation in a variable, except maybe as a string (but that is fraught with issues of its own). Your function will be evaluated the moment you execute, and the value of the output will instead be stored in the variable.  Furthermore, the [`^`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR) is not the power in Javascript-- you want [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).

Comment: you could use a function or an arrow function as formular, with parameters as variables in the formular.

Answer (score 0):

Save the power to a variable, and you can update it when needed. It is preferred that you put the equation into a function and pass power to it, and return the solution.

```js
var power = 1,
    eq    = function(p){
         return 50*1.07^+p; // returns solution
   }; 

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){

     power = i;

     console.log( eq(power) ); // solution

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store a state to the function that runs the equation. This helps you avoid adding more state outside of the function. Let the function keep track of how many times it has been called.

```js
function calc() {
  if (!this.i) {
    this.i = 1;
  }
  return (50 * Math.pow(1.07, this.i++));
}

console.log(calc());
console.log(calc());
console.log(calc());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your power in a variable and increment it each time your function is called.

```js
var power = 1;

function calculate() {
  console.log(50 * Math.pow(1.07, power));
  power++;
}

calculate();
calculate();
calculate();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can't really store an equation in a variable, except maybe as a string (but that is fraught with issues of its own).  Your function will be evaluated the moment you execute, and the value of the output will instead be stored in the variable.

To do what you want to do, you would be better having a function that runs the equation, and increments the power each time-- this works if the power is in a higher scope (or it can be accomplished with a closure)

```
var power = 1;
function getCost()
    var cost = Math.pow(50*1.07, power);
    power++;
    return cost;
}
```

Each time this function runs, it returns the calculated cost and also increments the value of power, so it will be one higher the next time it runs.

Alternately, if you wanted to go the closure route, you could do something like this:

```
var getCost = (function () {
    var power = 1;
    return function () {
        var cost = Math.pow(50*1.07, power);
        console.log(power);
        power++;
        return cost;
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) function is javascript for this.

You can use something like this

```
var pow = 1;
for(var power=1; power<limit; power++){ // run the loop upto a limit
 console.log(Math.pow(50*1.07, power);
}
```

Comment: That `int` should be `var`. *"JavaScript (not to be confused with Java) ..."*

Comment: yeah ..sry about that.. I was writing some Cpp code when i stumbled upon this :) thanks for correction @Adam

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function for it.

```
getCost = function (n) { return 50 * Math.pow(1.07, n); };
```

Or with ES6's [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
getCost = n => 50 * Math.pow(1.07, n);
```

Call it with

```
value = getCost(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

To increment power of `1.07` by 1, just multiply value by `1.07` every time (`pow` function is not needed at all)

```
 var mathForCost = 50 * 1.07;

    ... 
    mathForCost = mathForCost * 1.07;
```